# Pointing script to latest file

Tags: powershell

Looking to pull in latest file that does an update loop nightly. The script is pointing to a folder that has several files with the same naming convention, but different times.

Example:

```
File_Test04212019.csv
File_Test04222019.csv
File_Test04232019.csv
File_Test04242019.csv
File_Test04252019.csv
etc.
```

When I first ran this script it worked out fine, but after i edited a few files to update them to see if it'll pull another updated file...it is still trying to pull the previous file it originally pulled. This is the script I used below.

```
$dir = "C:\temp\File_Test*"
$filter = "*.csv"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter |
          Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending |
          Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Name

Import-Csv -Path $dir | ForEach-Object {
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Import-Csv : Cannot perform operation because the path resolved to more than
one file. This command cannot operate on multiple files.
At line:7 char:1
+ Import-Csv -Path $dir | ForEach-Object {
```

Any idea on how this can be resolved?

Comment: the `.LastAccesTime` prop is ... unreliable. instead, use the `.LastWriteTime`. i just edited a file and the LAT did NOT change ... but the LWT did change.

Comment: you define `$Dir` as a path and then use that in your Import-CSV command. you never use the `$Latest` variable ... so the path will always have all the matching files.

Comment: Sweet! I made my change to be: $dir = "C:\temp\File_Test*"
$filter= "*.csv"
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.Name

$outFile = 'C:\temp\empid_log.csv'
Import-Csv -Path $latest | ForEach-Object {   and it worked out perfect! thank you!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Forgot to tag you, thank you again!

Comment: you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lee Dailey, below is the answer.

```
$dir = "C:\temp\File_Test*" 
$filter = "*.csv" 
$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter $filter | Sort-Object LastWriteTime - 
           Descending | Select-Object -First 1 
$latest.Name $outFile = 'C:\temp\empid_log.csv' 

Import-Csv -Path $latest | ForEach-Object {
```